# msg.sender returing 0x000

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract TransferFunds{
    address owner;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    function TransferFunds() public
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
        return;
    }
    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public returns(address, uint, address, uint)
    {
        if (owner.balance < amount) return (msg.sender,owner.balance,receiver,balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Sent(owner, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

I used the following code as a program to transfer funds. I am running the code in Remix with the default JavaScript VM. I created the contract and then called the send function with the following arguments - "0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c",1

I can see some changes in the ether balance, but haven't been able to sort what the change is.

Meanwhile, when I am trying to check the balance of the account, it returns zero. I found that even msg.sender is 0x. Can you please help me figure out the problem. Please find the logs below.

```
    Contract getting created -
 status     0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
 contractAddress    0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a
 from   0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c
 to     TransferFunds.(constructor)

send getting calls -
status  0x1 Transaction mined and execution succeed
 from   0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c
 to     TransferFunds.send(address,uint256) 0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a
```

[image: Output Logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you only return something when `owner.balance < amount` is true.

In the case `owner.balance >= amount` the function will return default values of address and uint, ie a 0x0 address, 0 as uint.

You should add a return after the `Sent` event is generated.

Comment: I am curious to know when the "balances" variable will fetch the values to the table. So I changed the function as follows, with events.
    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public returns(address, uint, address, uint)
    {
        Start(owner, balances[msg.sender]);
        Start(receiver, balances[receiver]);
        if (owner.balance > amount) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
            balances[receiver] += amount;
            Sent(owner, receiver, amount);
        }
        return (msg.sender,owner.balance,receiver,balances[receiver]);
    }

Comment: The first two start events returned "0" from the balances[]. It was populated correctly later on. So when does the mapping table beformed ? 
 {
  "topic": "cfb9c5312b25ec7b809d61e638df25f749eae5d5c25399e1c93d1d319bfd5821",
  "event": "Start",
  "args": [
   "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c",
   "0"
  ]
 },
 {
  "topic": "cfb9c5312b25ec7b809d61e638df25f749eae5d5c25399e1c93d1d319bfd5821",
  "event": "Start",
  "args": [
   "0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c",
   "0"
  ]
 },